# Force change vue js/css assets hash (fingerprint)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Building vue app in production as in:

```
NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build
```

Adds the static assets hash fingerprints as below:

```
  dist/js/chunk-vendors.d710a916.js      986.81 KiB        297.69 KiB
  dist/js/app.ad3f94f2.js                231.00 KiB        56.02 KiB
  dist/3115008e.worker.js                30.59 KiB         9.98 KiB
  dist/css/app.7eecdb26.css              174.87 KiB        24.16 KiB
  dist/css/chunk-vendors.565b13d4.css    42.77 KiB         6.81 KiB
```

The assets are served with a high maxage cache. Due to some issues involving the headers of these static assets, I want to force renaming all assets, preferably via changing the length of the hash fingerprint (or the algorithm).

So in `vue.config.js` I added:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            hashFunction: 'sha256',
            hashDigestLength: 8,
        },
    ...
}
```

The problem is that it affects only `dist/3115008e.worker.js` (the hash changes, and length increases to 8). All other assets name remain unchanged.

What changes are required to modify the hash fingerprint length (or algorithm) for the chunk-vendors and app assets?

Answer (score 2):

Update:
I ended up forcing assets hash change by modifying the loader's `hashType` option in `vue.config.js`(which seem to default to 'md5'):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('vue')
        .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
            options.hashType = `sha1`
            return options
        })
},
```

I wasn't able to change the hash length. It seems to be hardcoded in `@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2"`